# Class 'Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I moved my Laravel application to production on a shared hosting. Now, I am getting this error message on all my pages. Not sure how to solve it. I believe I was using another version of Laravel when I copied over my vendor folders. I think I was using 4.2.6 and now I am using 4.2.8 on my dev.

`Class 'Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter' not found`

```
`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bindShared('encrypter', function($app)
        {
            $encrypter =  new Encrypter($app['config']['app.key']);

            if ($app['config']->has('app.cipher'))`
```

Comment: Have you run `composer update` in your project? It seems like a simply dependency mismatch problem.

Comment: I can't. I don't have access to SSH on my shared hosting.

Comment: This need not be a problem, if you can download the environment, run composer locally, then reupload.

Comment: True. I may can do that. I am re-uploading everything and then I will try that!